# Get enum string without toString()

Tags: java, enumeration

If I have something like this:

```
public enum Collection {
    Name, Type, All
}
```

And I would like to use the enumkey for the string too. I can say `Collection.Name.toString` - thats fine. But I would like to do this without `.toString` Is there an easy solution for this? I saw a lot of stuff but they were too big with `switch` or with a lot of `if`. No other way? Thank you!

Edit: the solution with `Collection.something.name()` is nice. But is there another way to get the string with `Collection.something` ?

Comment: What do you want to use it for? You mention `switch` and `if`, and that scares me.

Answer (score 10):

Use Enum's [`name()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name%28%29) method:

```
Collection.Name.name()
Collection.Type.name()
// etc
```

#### Edit:

I don't know if this is a valid solution, but this would work too:

```
Collection.Name + ""
```

Comment: Ok thats a good one. But let me change my question: how to do this without Collection.Name.anything()? :) So without .toString or .name or whatever

Comment: @OverStack, You want to get something without doing anything!? There is only one option for not doing anything and if that isn't enough, the answer would have to be, no.

Comment: Please edit the question to show some pseudo-code that demonstrates what you have in mind.

Answer (score 3):

It's looks like you are searching smt like

```
enum Collection {
    Name("name"), Type("type"), All("all");
    String id;

    Collection(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

or

```
enum Collection2 {
    Name, Type, All;
    private static final Map<Collection2, String> ids;

    static {
        ids = new HashMap<Collection2, String>();
        ids.put(Name, "name");
        ids.put(Type, "type");
        ids.put(All, "all");
        //here can be sam validation on id's uniq
    }

    public String getId() {
        return ids.get(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use name(), but it boils down to the same thing.

It's a fact that you'll add some extra verbosity to your program (and that's just what Java needs, extra verbosity), but the fact that each entry of your enumeration is an Object of type Collection doesn't give you much leverage. 
You can, in some scenarios, rely on the fact that toString will be called implicitly, but this is a situational  behavior, and not that great of an habit.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can avoid it is in building a String

```
"Collection type= " + Collection.Name.toString();
"Collection type= " + Collection.Name.name();
"Collection type= " + Collection.Name;
```

All do the same thing because it calls the `.toString()` for you.

You could do

```
String text = "" + Collection.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a weird work around, but it's possible to use an interface with String variables to achieve what you're going for--if I understand you correctly.
Example:

```
public interface myEnum {
    String Name = "Name";
    String Type = "Type";
    String All = "All";
}
```

Then, call like you would an enum:

```
if (myEnum.Name.equals("Name"))
    return true;
```

This avoids appending "toString()" to everything.